# Java using default constructor

Tags: java, constructor, multiple-constructors

I have hit a little problem with constructors at my program. It is a simple bank database which stores customer data. I have to implement methods for depositing, withdrawing and transferring cash between two accounts. I have implemented that kind of constructor to add new bank account:

```java
public Customer() {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter id of customer:");
        this.id = scan.nextLine();
        File folder = new File("CustomerDataBase" + File.separator + this.id + ".txt");
        if(folder.exists()) {
            System.out.println("Customer ID already exists!");
            System.exit(1);
        }  
        try {      
            System.out.println("Enter name of customer:");
            this.name = scan.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Enter surname of customer:");
            this.surname = scan.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Enter PESEL number of customer:");
            this.pesel = scan.nextLine();           
            System.out.println("Enter address of customer:");
            System.out.println("    Street:");
            this.adressStreet = scan.nextLine();
            System.out.println("    City:");
            this.adressCity = scan.nextLine();
            System.out.println("    Zip Code: ");
            this.zipCode = scan.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Enter funds of Customer:");
            this.funds = Double.parseDouble(scan.nextLine());
            this.saveCustomer();
            scan.close();
        }catch(NumberFormatException e) {
            System.out.println("Error : " + e);
            System.exit(1);
        }   
    }
```

And then I have a method `withdraw` :

```java
static void withdraw (int amount, int id) {

    File f = new File("CustomerDataBase" + File.separator + String.valueOf(id) + ".txt");
    Scanner fRead;

    Customer tempCustomer = new Customer();

    try{
        fRead = new Scanner(f);
        tempCustomer.id = fRead.nextLine();
        tempCustomer.name = fRead.nextLine();
        tempCustomer.surname = fRead.nextLine();
        tempCustomer.pesel = fRead.nextLine();
        tempCustomer.adressStreet = fRead.nextLine();
        tempCustomer.adressCity = fRead.nextLine();
        tempCustomer.zipCode = fRead.nextLine();
        tempCustomer.funds = Double.parseDouble(fRead.nextLine()) - id;
        fRead.close();
        tempCustomer.saveCustomer();
    }catch(FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("File not found!");
        System.exit(1);
    }   
}
```

The `withdraw` method reads data from file and have to stores it in class. So I'm creating object as customer type. But I want to use just "plain" (default) constructor which Java provides when you do not declare your own.
How to do that? I read about `super():` statement, but if I understood it right, it works only when you inherit from another class.

Comment: Your `customer` class defined a constructor of its own, so the default plain one isn't created...

Comment: The constructor he declared IS the default constructor, since he declared it as a no-args constructor

Comment: Which is why there isn't a "plain" one (the word 'default' is a bit misleading here)

Comment: BTW - You should not embed the majority of your program logic within a constructor. The constructor is only intended to be used for initialization. Instead, create another method like - processInput() and call that method on an instance of your object.

Comment: You can only call super() if it is the first line in the constructor. If omitted, it is called implicitly by default. All Classes inherit from a class. If you don;t explicitly extends another class, you are extending the Class Object by default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every class comes with a default constructor that is not visible in the class itself. **However, please note that if you specify a constructor other than the default constructor, the default constructor can't be used, per @Rustam comment below.** For example, let's say your Customer class looks like this:

```
public class Customer {

    private String name;

    private String lastName;

    private age int;

    private String ssn;

    //default constructor that is NOT visible
    Customer()
    {

    }

    //other constructor given name and lastName
    Customer(name, lastName)
    {
        this.name = name;

        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    //getters and setters

}
```

The constructor Customer() is created by default and it is not necessary for you to include in your class.

You can then create a customer instance using the default constructor and then you would need to use setters to set the properties, like follows:

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String [] args){

        Customer c = new Customer();

        //setting parameters
        c.setName("Jose");

        c.setLastName("Mejia");

    }

}
```

Comment: Default constructor without parameters implicitly added by compiler IF NO OTHER CONSTRUCTOR specified for class. So if class have only one constructor Customer(String name, String lastName), then you can't create instance with new Customer().

Comment: Correct. I forgot to add that to the answer. I will add now. You didn't have to -1 me